# PHP - simple condition not working

Tags: php

I have a very weird condition with my php script.

```
$qType = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'qType', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if ($qType == 1) {
..
elseif ($qType == 3) { 
$prod = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'prod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    echo "prod = " . $prod;
    if ($prod == "SiHy")
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.table_s";
    else
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.table_fl";
..
}
echo $strSQL;
```

I called it this way:

```
http://localhost/new.php?qType=3&prod="SiHy"
```

And it always returns *FROM dbo.table_fl*. Even when I put the condition as != and put the table_fl on top, it always returns *FROM dbo.table_s* -> the second $strSQL value setting.

What happened? What am I doing wrong? Seems like the **if** is not working.

Thanks in advance,
:rherry

Comment: when your condition not working, just echo out the values for your variable before if statement, to check the value

Comment: What are you getting in $prod? Try var_dump() to see what is inside?

Comment: did you try it this way: `http://localhost/new.php?qType=3&prod=SiHy` without the quotes in the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are passing the quotation marks.

So either change your condition to

```
if ($prod == "\"SiHy\"")
```

or change your URL to

```
http://localhost/new.php?qType=3&prod=SiHy
```

Comment: Thanks, Arunas. Yes, I changed it to `== "'SiHy'"` does the work.

Comment: @rherry: by using an if statement this way, you're only checking one option, leaving the other as the default or fall-back.  I'd suggest explicitly checking a condition for each one, and having a default that tells you it can't identify the prod.  switch or select statements work well for this